# Plot random gaussian samples subjected to be under a boundary line in R

Tags: r, plot, svm

For some documentation, I need to make an example plot of 2 classes of Gaussian variable in (x,y). For the sake of simplicity, let's say that the regions are linearly separable so I can visually isolate these two regions (it' for an example only, no real numbers are needed)

Let's say I have linear decision boundary. Is there a compact way to scatter plot the region 1 (those below the boundary) with one symbol/color and the ones in region 2 (over the boundary) with another symbol/color?

Comment: Yes, there is a way. To show you, I'd need some example data and you to explain more clearly, what the plot should look like (maybe provide a mock-up).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just want different points above and below a line like `y = 2*x`, right?

In base R:

```
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- rnorm(100)
type <- y<2*x
plot(x,y,pch=type+1)
abline(0,2)
```

Just use a variable like `type` to change the symbol using `pch` (you could also change the color using `col`).  The `abline()` function plots a line with intercept = 0 and slope = 2.

Using `ggplot`:

```
require(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(x,y,type)
ggplot(df,aes(x,y,shape=type)) + geom_point() + geom_abline(slope=2)
```

If you wanted to have the points be different colors, you could tack on `color=type` after or instead of `shape=type`.

Comment: I assume you mean base R (and not SAS)?

Comment: And `plot(x,y, pch=type+1)` would be simpler.

Comment: @Roland Right on both accounts.  I have to use both SAS and R, unfortunately, so I sometimes have SAS on the brain.  The `pch=type+1` is a great trick.  I wish I had thought of it.